# if statement to select online db if available else select local db

Tags: php

**if statement to select online db if available else select local db**

In a project a internet is available the program use a server database. if internet is not available it will store on the local database.

Comment: check out the error codes output of whatever function you're using to connect to the db, then add an if() block acordingly.

Comment: Ok. Ok. That's Good. But, **Where is your code** , which you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] === 'localhost'){

$_SESSION['vURL'] = 'http://localhost/example/';

}else{

    $_SESSION['vURL'] = 'http://www.example.com/';

    }
```

this defines a variable called vURL which can be used when linking to other pages. E.G

```
<a href="<?php echo vURL; ?>about.php">About Us</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

**connection_aborted**: `Check whether client disconnected`

> Returns 1 if client disconnected, 0 otherwise.

For More Info, Check [connection-aborted - PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php)

```
if(connection_aborted() == 0)
{
    //Select Online DB
}
else
{
    //Select Local DB
}
```